# Getting the picoflexx depth sensor working on ROS [solved]

Tags: ros, camera, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to get the picoflexx depth sensor working with ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.
I can run the normal royaleviewer.sh from the official package "libroyale-1.0.5.40-LINUX-64Bit", and the depth camera is working fine.
Then I tried this wrapper here : https://github.com/fmina/ros_picoflexx
It compiles fine, but when I run the launch file, I got this error :

```
process[firefly/picoflexx_cam-1]: started with pid [9406]
[ INFO] [1445772351.805227168]: Detecting cameras...
Detected 1 camera(s).
[firefly/picoflexx_cam-1] process has died [pid 9406, exit code -11, cmd /home/cyril/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ros_picoflexx/ros_picoflexx_node __name:=picoflexx_cam __log:=/home/cyril/.ros/log/e35b1f4c-7b07-11e5-9dd2-247703332438/firefly-picoflexx_cam-1.log].
log file: /home/cyril/.ros/log/e35b1f4c-7b07-11e5-9dd2-247703332438/firefly-picoflexx_cam-1*.log
```

Using rosrun leads to a segmentation fault, which is why we see exit code -11 I think.
Anyone got this error and found how to fix that ?

FIRST EDIT (This was the old workaround fix) :

As suggested by gvdhoorn, I've run the node with GDB by adding to the node parameters : launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args".

So the segmentation fault occur in the function void PicoFlexxCamera::Initialize(), when it's checking the camera id.
As a workaround, I've just removed the if condition.
The original code is :

```
for (int i = 0; i < camlist.size(); i++) {
    if (camlist[i] == camera_id_) {
      camera_device_ = manager_.createCamera(camlist[i]);
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(camera_name_ << " initialized correctly");
    }
}
```

So I just commented out the if :

```
for (int i = 0; i < camlist.size(); i++) {
     //if (camlist[i] == camera_id_) {
          camera_device_ = manager_.createCamera(camlist[i]);
          ROS_INFO_STREAM(camera_name_ << " initialized correctly");
     //}
}
```

The node works well, I can visualize the PointCloud2 in rviz. If someone has a better solution, please post it.

SECOND EDIT : Now the new code in the repository works fine (at this time there is just a ':' missing in the src/ros_picoflexx_node.cc file, you will get notified when launching catkin_make, just add it, this will get fix soon I think), you have to launch it once to get the camera ID and enter it in the yaml parameter file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219817/getting-the-picoflexx-depth-sensor-working-on-ros-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2015-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-25**:
Try to get a [gdb backtrace](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbstack.html#BACKTRACE), to pinpoint where the thing is crashing. See [Roslaunch Nodes in Valgrind or GDB](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) for info on running nodes with gdb.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-10-28**:
Thanks a lot for your advice, I managed to run the node with GDB and found where the issue was, I'll edit my post.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-28**:
I'd be more inclined to call that a workaround. Something is wrong with the way `camlist` is being indexed, most likely. Perhaps you should keep this question open, at least until [fmina/ros_picoflexx/issues/6](https://github.com/fmina/ros_picoflexx/issues/6) is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixes are done, please check https://github.com/fmina/ros_picoflexx/issues/6

---

Originally posted by [fmina](https://answers.ros.org/users/24961/fmina/) with karma: 36 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-11-03**:
Thanks, just a ':' missing in the src file.

**Comment by [aditagabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29561/aditagabbar/) on 2017-03-04**:
Hi There, I used your drivers and got it working they are really very helpful. And, I also wanted to learn how to go about writing them from scratch. Can you suggest me some resources or links to go through which might give me a starting point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I also wrote a driver for the pmd CamBoard pico flexx, because there was none, when I looked for one. It is available at https://github.com/code-iai/pico_flexx_driver. The driver publishes the point cloud and depth / ir / noise images on topics, supports dynamic reconfigure and zero copy nodelets. Feel free to try it out.

---

Originally posted by [Thiemo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5332/thiemo/) with karma: 31 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aditagabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29561/aditagabbar/) on 2017-03-04**:
Hi There, I used your drivers and got it working they are really very helpful. And, I also wanted to learn how to go about writing them from scratch. Can you suggest me some resources or links to go through which might give me a starting point. Thanks